# get execution time of bubble sort

Tags: python

I'm trying to print the execution time of a bubble sort, but it keep asking an Integer

"TypeError: an integer is required (got type NoneType)"

```
import time


def bubbleSort(array):
    # loop to access each array element
    for i in range(len(array)):

        # loop to compare array elements
        for j in range(0, len(array) - i - 1):

            # compare two adjacent elements
            # change > to < to sort in descending order
            if array[j] > array[j + 1]:
                # swapping elements if elements
                # are not in the intended order
                temp = array[j]
                array[j] = array[j + 1]
                array[j + 1] = temp


def get_time(arg):
    start = time.time()
    time.sleep(arg) 
    end = time.time()
    return end-start

time = get_time(bubbleSort(list))
print(time)
```

Comment: What is `get_time(bubbleSort(list))` supposed to do? Why are you sleeping in get_time? What is list? If anything you should call it `get_time(list)` and have get_time do `bubbleSort(arg)` instead of sleeping.

Comment: your `bubbleSort` function does not return a value, you haven't shown the traceback but i assume this is where the unexpected `None` is coming from (i.e. you are passing `None` to `get_time`)

Comment: `list` is a Python built-in, so `bubbleSort(list)` looks wrong - use a different name for your variable if you have stored a list in it

Comment: use https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html for measuring performance of code, it will produce better results than writing your own timing code

Comment: and as @luk2302 said, your `get_time` function is not able to measure the execution time of `bubbleSort` because the way function calls work - first `bubbleSort` is called, then its result is passed to `get_time`, so `get_time` is just measuring the sleep time ... if you wanted to write your own it would need to be implemented as a decorator or a context-manager

Answer (score 0):

Your program does not work the way you think it works:

What you seem to be trying, is to make `get_time()` wait until `bubbleSort()` is finished. Hence the `time.sleep()` call inside of it.

What actually happens is, the innermost function `bubbleSort()` gets called first, and its return value - `None` gets passed into the `get_time()` function.

Here is the fixed get_time call:

```
def get_time():
    start = time.time()
    bubbleSort(list)
    end = time.time()
    return end-start

time = get_time()
```

EDIT:

If you want to call different functions, simply pass the function as the argument:

```
def get_time(my_func):
    start = time.time()
    my_func(list)
    end = time.time()
    return end-start

time1 = get_time(bubbleSort)
time2 = get_time(quickSort)
```

Comment: Yes, thank you. But i need the get_time function to work with multiple types of sorting, like selection and quick sort.

I tryied to replace the "bubbleSort(list)" by "function" and change the name to get_time(function) but it returned 0.0